# Do seventh chords have more inversions than triads?

Tags: chord-inversions

Because seventh chords have four notes, wouldn't it make them have more inversions than a triad?

Comment: sorry for basic question, I just wasn't completely sure.

Comment: It's a basic but perfectly valid question. I don't know why it got down votes.

Comment: @mistercoffee66 - possibly because mathematically if nothing else, it's fairly obvious - thus virtually rhetorical?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. They have root position, first inversion and second inversion which we have also seen with triads and are exactly the same with the root on the bottom, the 3rd on the bottom, and the 5th on the bottom respectively. However we also now have third inversion which has the 7th on the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - the more notes avaiable in any chord the more inversions you can have.

An inversion is named purely by its lowest note, so since seventh chords by definition are comprised of four notes, ther will be, in rising order named from the lowest note they are roo, 1st, 2nd *and* 3rd inversions. The last probably sounding the weakest.

Of course with four notes, there are more voicings available as well.

*Root* in key C could be C E G B, C E B G, C G B E, C G E B, C B E G, or  C B G E. All of which are playable on piano at least.

Answer (score 1):

yes, they do. You are correct.